# How do I open / edit a ".sdb" file (SAP2000 Database)

Tags: database

I'm have ".sdb" database file. I need to open it. It's the database behind  of SAP2000 program ([csiamerica.com](http://csiamerica.com))

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I bet you can open it with SAP2000.

Comment: i want to open the database file of SAP2000

Comment: Yes, and you can open it in SAP2000. If you want to open it using something else, you should expand your question and describe what _exactly_ it is that you want to do.

Comment: I'm try to develop a program base on SAP2000 product. I want to read and write in  ".sdb" file.

Answer (score 0):

Try working with the .$2k file instead of the .sdb
It is much more convenient and it can be imported to SAP2000.